# Best mBass for realtime iOS Location Sharing

Tags: ios, parse-platform, firebase, backend

I've been using Parse.com for all of my apps for a while and currently have a working version of a location sharing app that I am developing, which updates users' location every 50 meters. Parse is sometimes very slow and does not update in realtime, so I have to have a timer to query the server every 15 seconds which can take up a lot of API requests.

Can I accomplish a more streamlined realtime updating system with Parse, or should I be searching for a new backend service, such as Firebase or others. Not sure how to choose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a real-time database, where updates can be sent to the server and then synced to all of your connected users. There's also offline persistence, where if the client loses an internet connection, the device will keep a local copy of the changes and make updates once it reconnects to the internet. If you'd like to know more, you can check out the iOS [quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html) and [guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/).